# match values from a range into each row of a table in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've been working on a multi tiered drop down program, and in filtering one of the tables I stumbled upon a problem I can't find any help on.

Basically, I have 2 sheets. Sheet1!A2:A has a set of values. In this example, A2=110, A3=114, A4=162. However, with each use of the program, there could be any number of values and the values could change.

In the second sheet, Sheet2! there is a table. The first row has the headers that I want to return from my search. Under each header is a series of numbers ranging from 3 to well over 50 values. And the number of columns is also unknown...(it will keep getting larger).

So I want to know which columns have all 3 values from Sheet1!A2:A in them.

Column 3 might have 6 numbers (95,110,114,125,150,162) and column 7 might have (80,110,114,125) so I would want to return the header from Column 3 but not from column 7.

Does any of this make sense? Again in simple terms, I want to query all of the columns in Sheet2 to see which contain all of the values from Sheet1!A2:A

Any help would be so greatly appreciated...

-Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up an sheet using your example data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/169VrbWkTlRMzhNPe4G8hQL1MdfqQuTvjb87aRD9hiWo/edit#gid=1923440782

I've restricted the formula in cell D2 to 500 rows for the sake of speed but you can remove the references to make it work across the whole sheet:

`=FILTER(Sheet2!1:1,ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(mmult(TRANSPOSE(COUNTIF(A2:A500,Sheet2!A2:Z500)),TRANSPOSE(split(rept("1,",COLUMNS(TRANSPOSE(COUNTIF(A2:A500,Sheet2!A2:Z500)))),",")))=count(A2:A500))))`

Comment: I can't freakin' believe it! I'm going to spend the next few days figuring out what all of this means, and playing around with different versions. I never got a good understanding of MMULT, so time to learn. Chris, I can't thank you enough for this.